# git merge, push, pull confusion

Tags: git

I have a git repository, R, which is cloned on machines A and B.  I made changes to the code on both A and B.  Then I pushed A back to R.  Now I would like to merge in the changes on B, and get A and B back in sync.

On B, I ran git pull.  This did some stuff.  (What I don't know.  How can I check or should I have said: git pull --no-commit ?)

If I now run, git push, will that put these changes into the respository?
If so, how do I bring A back into sync.  Is this a git pull on A?

Thanks.

Comment: If you seriously don't understand what a `git pull` does and what will happen when you do a `git push` you need to take your hands off the keyboard before you destroy one (or all three) of your repositories. I am not trying to be insulting, but you are at risk of dong serious damage to your codebase. Now read the Pro Git book [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) which is an excellent resource and will get you up to speed.

Comment: As a general rule, stay away from `git pull`, at least at the beginning. Use `git fetch`, followed by the adequate `git merge` command instead. When you have a better understanding of Git, you can start using `git pull`, if you think it makes your life any easier.

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: Changes were made to `B` when you did a `git pull` on `B`. You can push the merged changes between `B` and `R` when you `push` to `R`. But as Judobs says, `git pull` can be dangerous when you don't know what changes you're pulling.

Comment: I'm on linux.  BTW, I am aware of my ignorance.  Problem is if I wait until I am an expert to start, it will be too late.  I am also tainted by a lifetime of CVS.  But I think I have this one.  The push did update the remote repository and the pull did update machine A.  Thanks.

Comment: I've walked you through the entire sequence in my answer. Note `git`s ability to clone, push, and fetch from local directories - not just physically remote masters. It's a very useful approach for experimenting. The only trick is initially setting up the bare repository at the start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Unix-like OS, the following commands will set up the situation you describe in your question.

```
mkdir play && cd play
mkdir Rtemp && cd Rtemp
git init
echo "This is file 1" > file1.txt
echo "This is file 2" > file2.txt
git add file?.txt && git commit -m "Initial Commit"
cd ..
git clone --bare Rtemp R
git clone R A
git clone R B
cd A
echo "edited file 1 in A" >> file1.txt
git commit -a -m "Edited file 1 in A"
cd ../B
echo "edited file 1 in B" >> file1.txt
echo "edited file 2 in B" >> file2.txt
git commit -a -m "Edited both files in B"
cd ..
```

At this point you have a central repo in `R` and two clones in `A` and `B`. `file.txt` has been edited in both `A` and `B`, and `file2.txt` has been edited in `B`.

Now you push up the changes from `A` to `R`

```
$ cd A
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 304 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To .../play/R
   34307cc..2a925ac  master -> master
```

At this point, `R` and `A` are in sync. `B` has local changes, and is one commit behind `R` - but doesn't know it until you do a `git fetch` (which is implied in a `git pull`).

```
$ cd ../B
$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From .../play/R
   34307cc..2a925ac  master     -> origin/master
$
```

The output from the `fetch` shows you that git has downloaded the state of the upstream repository. A `git status` will show you how you stand.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

The warning sign here is the note that `Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged`. This says you will need to do a merge, and the way I set this up there should be conflicts

```
$ git merge origin/master
Auto-merging file1.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file1.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ git status
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both modified:   file1.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Note that it is only complaining about `file1.txt`. Git was able to merge the changes to `file2.txt` as it was only changed locally. If you now `cat file1.txt` you will see the following

```
$ cat file1.txt
This is file 1
<<<<<<< HEAD
edited file 1 in B
=======
edited file 1 in A
>>>>>>> origin/master
```

The pairs of `<<<<<<<` and `>>>>>>` show the areas of conflict. There may be many of them in each file in a real merge. Now you need to decide how you want `file1.txt` to look like after the merge, and edit it to make it so. Assume we want to keep both lines, with our local edit occurring after the one from upstream. So we edit it and `file1.txt` now looks like this:

```
$ vi file1.txt
$ cat file1.txt
This is file 1
edited file 1 in A
edited file 1 in B
```

(Note we removed the conflict markers)

Now we need to complete the merge, and push our commits back to `R`

```
$ git add file1.txt 
$ git commit -m "Resolved conflicts"
[master 5454980] Resolved conflicts
$ git log --oneline
5454980 Resolved conflicts
1673d76 Edited both files in B
2a925ac Edited file 1 in A
34307cc Initial Commit
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 650 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To .../play/R
   2a925ac..5454980  master -> master
```

At this point, `B` and `R` are in sync, but now `A` is behind master again.

```
$ cd ../A
$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 7 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), done.
From /home/keith/play/gitplay/R
   2a925ac..5454980  master     -> origin/master
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

This time `git status` lets us know we can 'fast forward` - which means there will be no conflicts.

```
$ git merge origin/master
Updating 2a925ac..5454980
Fast-forward
 file1.txt | 1 +
 file2.txt | 1 +
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 git merge origin/master
$ git log --oneline
5454980 Resolved conflicts
1673d76 Edited both files in B
2a925ac Edited file 1 in A
34307cc Initial Commit
```

Finally, `A`, `B`, and `R` are all in agreement and both developers can continue to work.

This seems like a lot of work, but it is a *very* basic workflow that you will quickly get used to.

Once you really know what you are doing, you will be comfortable enough with git to safely use `git pull` and its evil (but incredibly useful) form `git pull --rebase`. But until then, stick with `git fetch` and `git merge`.